# undefined = true; then back to undefined?

Tags: javascript, undefined

Some javascript tomfoolery:

If this works

```
undefined = true;
```

then how can you revert back to set `undefined` back to representing `undefined`?

---

Sure, the easy way is to store `undefined` in another variable before setting `undefined` to `true`.  What other way can you restore `undefined`?

First thought to set it back was `delete undefined;`, didn't work.

Comment: In most browsers, `window.undefined` is not writable; even after executing `window.undefined=true`, `window.undefined` still evaluates to `undefined`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined . (`undefined` is a property of the global `window` object, so `undefined` and `window.undefined` are equivalent.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725586/undefined-true-then-back-to-undefined/5725602#5725602) is the *safe and practical* way to ensure `undefined` is really undefined.

But JS is super flexible, so **for fun**, if you wish to revert the *global* `undefined`, then you can reassign `window.undefined` from the safety of a new function scope:

```
(function () {            // Create a new scope
   var a;                 // "a" is undefined in this scope
   window.undefined = a;  // Set the global "undefined" to "a"
})()                      // Execute immediately
```

---

Taking this idea futher, you can reconfigure the above to become:

```
undefined = (function () {
   var a;                 // "a" is undefined
   return a;              // return "a"
})();
```

---

Or really, just this:

```
undefined = (function () {
    return;
})();
```

---

But in fact, you don't actually need to return anything:

```
undefined = function(){}();
```

---

Of course, then there's also the [`void` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/void) ;-) **doh!**

```
undefined = void 0;
```

Comment: Damn, just came here to edit `void` into my answer, and you beat me to it :P

Comment: @alex haha yeah, I completely forgot about it earlier too.

Answer (score 7):

```
(function(undefined) {

   // undefined is undefined again!

})();
```

jQuery uses this pattern.

[`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/operators/special_operators/delete_operator) operator is best for deleting properties from objects. There are a number of things it won't work on, and using it with an `Array` just sets the element to `undefined` (sort of, it won't be enumerated with `in`). Best to use `splice()` with an `Array`.